# failed to redirect page using cookie values in jsf

Tags: jsf, cookies

i already got the value of cookie. but the redirect to other page method doesnt work. it only returns blank page.. im referring to whenever the user directly access it at the addressbar. i want them to redirect to homepage instead of the page they want to access.. using the value of my cookies

heres the snippet.

```
 if(regdate before or after endregdate) {create cookie with value something}
    else {create cookie with value something}
```

im using ExternalContext redirect(ec.getrequestcontextpath + "/homepage.xhtml");

then my xhtml they're trying to access have this `<f:event listener="#{bean.redirectPageMethod}" type="preRenderView">`

ADDED SNIPPET:
im trying to use this snippet but still doesn't work..

```
<f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="cookieValue" value="#{bean.cookieValue}"/>       
            <f:event listener="#{bean.redirectPage}" type="preRenderView"/>

            </f:metadata>
```

here's my redirectpageMethod

```
public void redirectPage() throws IOException{
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();

    Cookie cookie = null;

    Cookie[] cookieList = request.getCookies();
    if(cookieList != null && cookieList.length > 0) {
        for(int index = 0 ; index < cookieList.length ; index++) {
            if(cookieList[index].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("AppCookie")) {
                cookie = cookieList[index];
                System.out.println("COOKIE FETCH");
                break;
            }
        }
    } 

    if(cookie.getValue().equals("0")) {
            externalContext.redirect(externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/homepage.xhtml");
            System.out.println("THIS COOKIE VALUE IS ZERO");
    }

}
```

Comment: @BalusC there is nothing in the view-page-source. even a single code

Comment: @BalusC still getting the blank page. :/